# Which Java version should I target for 12.04 installations?

Tags: 12.04, java, development

I am considering developing a Java application for Ubuntu. The page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java doesn't say which (if any) comes by default.

Also, I know many people change their Java version to run applications like Minecraft.

What version are people running - or is Java just a poor choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default version in 12.04 is OpenJDK 6 (`openjdk-6-jre`, aka `default-jre`) (although OpenJDK 7 is installable). The default in 12.10 is OpenJDK 7.

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) is an open-source implementation of the Java specification. It is generally fully compatible with the "official" Oracle/Sun Java implementation (but there are a few edge cases where parts of the original JDK were licence encumbered, eg with fonts where the implementations can slightly differ). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa) discusses the issue a bit.

Unless there are features in Java 7 you really want to use, I would recommend targeting OpenJDK 6, which should work with the vast majority of Java installations, both on Ubuntu and other platforms.

Comment: Thank you chronitis. Is it installed by default or do Ubuntu users have to go looking in the Software Centre for it?

Comment: It is not installed by default, but it should be the first result when searching for "java" in the Software Centre or can be installed with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre` (or `openjdk-7-jre`).